# Place Line from Text File in a Shell CMD. VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am assuming there is a way to have this sub in? I am assuming Do Until Loop is the way to go, I just do not know how to contruct one.

```vb
    Sub Main()
    'Declare Command
    Dim sCommand As String
    'Declare File where Users are Located
    Dim strFile As String = "C:\TestDUsers.txt"
    'Running from Admin Comptuer so permissions are fine
    'Want to replace the ******** section with each username from text file
    sCommand = "pushd \\*********\C$ && whoami.exe >> C:\File.txt"

    'Load the File and perform the loop????

    Using sr As New StreamReader(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Open))

    End Using

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Clear()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this if I understand your question correct:

```
Sub Main()
    HandleJavaInfo()
End Sub

Sub HandleJavaInfo()
    Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\pseal2\Desktop\TestDUsers.txt"
    Dim strCommand = "pushd \\*********\C$ && whoami.exe >> C:\Users\pseal2\Desktop\Javainfo."

    Dim strLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFile)
    For Each strUserName As String In strLines

        'execute the command as shell or process

        'Example using Shell (run the command whitout showing the window for the user)
        Dim ThisCommand As String = strCommand.Replace("*********", strUserName)
        Shell(ThisCommand, AppWinStyle.Hide)

        'Example using process
        Process.Start("pushd", "\\" & strUserName & "\C$ && whoami.exe >> C:\Users\pseal2\Desktop\Javainfo.")

    Next
End Sub
```

Now, you have only told us what you want to DO, not what you want to achieve. If you tell us exactly what the goal is, then it may be some other .Net ways to do what you want, instead of shelling out to a DOS-command, and you can get more accurate answers.

Comment: Basically anyway that will insert each user name form a txt file and run the said commands on it. I am troubleshooting it again now and will edit shortly

Comment: That worked.I needed to do Shell("cmd.exe /c" & ThisCommand) to not have it throw an error. Could have just been my fault.


It seems that when it tries to move onto the next Line in the File it says File is already in Use. For example I should be able to list my personall computer in the USER text file twice and have it return the results twice.